# Interpretation of TGA-DSC data in terms of composition of iron oxides

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science, data-analysis

I have thermogravimetric (TGA) and differential scanning calorimetry (DSA) data for an iron (hyd)oxide sample and I would like to interpret this data in terms of the composition of the starting material.

Measurements have been made in Air and He over the temperature range 30-700 degrees C. From the TGA I can observe the mass lost which is ~20% at 300 degrees C and ~25% at 700 degrees C. From the DSA I can see there is exothermic event occurring at 415 degrees C which can be attributed to a phase transformation to hematite (Fe2O3) at which point some 23% of original mass is lost.

Given I know the final product's formula (i.e. Fe2O3) and I know the mass lost is it possible for me to infer the starting material's formula e.g. by assuming H2O is lost?

I am new to this kind of data and could really do with a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks